# JavaScript for (pasting!) only numbers in a textfield

Tags: javascript, numbers, formfield, pasting

I'm using [this script](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_158.html) to have a textfield with only numbers, and it works just fine, only my users cant past a number, and as I need 7+ digits, I guess a lot of people will be using copy paste.

I saw some solutions which use jquery, but seams a bit too heavy for me, and there mus be some light elegant solution which allows pasting?

Comment: JavaScript that tries to restrict what I can type, or automatically changes focus from one field to another are extremely annoying.

Comment: Yeah. Why not validate afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `number` type introduced in HTML5:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="9999999">
```

It’s not supported everywhere, but you can add a fallback for IE using the `input.onpropertychange` event and check for `window.event.propertyName == 'value'` inside the handler to listen for any changes in the input field.

For other browsers, you can try the "input" event. Or simply validate and modify on `blur` to be nicer to the user.

As others have mentioned, it’s considered bad practice to do this as the user types. The `number` attribute adds a pretty decent way of handling this on it’s own.

Comment: It's not good to pretend that IE is always the only browser that lacks support for the particular feature. In this case, both `<input type=number>` and the `onpropertychange` event aren't supported in Firefox.

Comment: @duri right, agreed. But my point was to add a fallback for unsupported browsers, and the example was just an example for one of them. FF support the 'input' event, so you can use that for FF. But I didn’t want to paste and entire library....